# Why does std::ends cause string comparison to fail?

Tags: c++, stl, boost

I spent about 4 hours yesterday trying to fix this issue in my code. I simplified the problem to the example below.

The idea is to store a string in a `stringstream` ending with `std::ends`, then retrieve it later and compare it to the original string.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    const std::string HELLO( "hello" );

    std::stringstream testStream;

    testStream << HELLO << std::ends;

    std::string hi = testStream.str();

    if( HELLO == hi )
    {
        std::cout << HELLO << "==" << hi << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can probably guess, the above code when executed will not print anything out.

Although, if printed out, or looked at in the debugger (VS2005), `HELLO` and `hi` look identical, their `.length()` in fact differs by 1. That's what I am guessing is causing the `==` operator to fail.

My question is why. I do not understand why `std::ends` is an invisible character added to string `hi`, making `hi` and `HELLO` different lengths even though they have identical content. Moreover, this invisible character does not get trimmed with boost trim. However, if you use `strcmp` to compare `.c_str()` of the two strings, the comparison works correctly.

The reason I used `std::ends` in the first place is because I've had issues in the past with `stringstream` retaining garbage data at the end of the stream. `std::ends` solved that for me.

Comment: Okay, I understand the mechanics behind this, but I don't like the semantics. It seems like I have two choices: don't use std::ends and risk having garbage data, or do use it and add custom code to get rid of extra NULL characters.

Comment: You should try to engineer your code so that you know what the expectations of the strings are - for example if you are reading strings from a network device they are probably not null terminated, but that would depend on the API you were using, but if you are passing strings around inside your app then probably they are. Don't get in a situation where you have no idea what is in your data.

Comment: Why are you using ends anyway? That's only used when you are building up a null terminated C style string from raw data. Here, in your example, its clearly not appropriate. You already have a C++ string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::ends` inserts a null character into the stream. Getting the content as a `std::string` will retain that null character and create a string with that null character at the respective positions.

So indeed a std::string can contain embedded null characters. The following std::string contents *are* different:

```
ABC
ABC\0
```

A binary zero is not whitespace. But it's also not printable, so you won't see it (unless your terminal displays it specially).

Comparing using `strcmp` will interpret the content of a `std::string` as a C string when you pass `.c_str()`. It will say

> Hmm, characters before the first `\0` (terminating null character) are *ABC*, so i take it the string is *ABC*

And thus, it will not see any difference between the two above. You are probably having this issue:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "hello";
s.seekp(0);
s << "b";
assert(s.str() == "b"); // will fail!
```

The assert will fail, because the sequence that the stringstream uses is still the old one that contains "hello". What you did is just overwriting the first character. You want to do this:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "hello";
s.str(""); // reset the sequence
s << "b";
assert(s.str() == "b"); // will succeed!
```

Also read this answer: [How to reuse an ostringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream/624291#624291)

Answer (score 4):

`std::ends` is simply a null character. Traditionally, strings in C and C++ are terminated with a null (ascii 0) character, however it turns out that `std::string` doesn't really require this thing. Anyway to step through your code point by point we see a few interesting things going on:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
```

The string literal `"hello"` is a traditional zero terminated string constant. We copy that whole into the `std::string` HELLO.

```
    const std::string HELLO( "hello" );

    std::stringstream testStream;
```

We now put the `string` HELLO (including the trailing 0) into the `stream`, followed by a second null which is put there by the call to `std::ends`.

```
    testStream << HELLO << std::ends;
```

We extract out a copy of the stuff we put into the `stream` (the literal string "hello", plus the two null terminators).

```
    std::string hi = testStream.str();
```

We then compare the two strings using the `operator ==` on the `std::string` class. This operator (probably) compares the length of the `string` objects - including how ever many trailing null characters. Note that the `std::string` class does not require the underlying character array to end with a trailing null - put another way it allows the string to contain null characters so the first of the two trailing null characters is treated as part of the string `hi`.

Since the two strings are different in the number of trailing nulls, the comparison fails.

```
    if( HELLO == hi )
    {
        std::cout << HELLO << "==" << hi << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Although, if printed out, or looked at
>   in the debugger (VS2005), HELLO and hi
>   look identical, their .length() in
>   fact differs by 1. That's what I am
>   guessing is causing the "==" operator
>   to fail.

Reason being, the length is different by one trailing null character.

> My question is why. I do not
>   understand why std::ends is an
>   invisible character added to string
>   hi, making hi and HELLO different
>   lengths even though they have
>   identical content. Moreover, this
>   invisible character does not get
>   trimmed with boost trim. However, if
>   you use strcmp to compare .c_str() of
>   the two strings, the comparison works
>   correctly.

`strcmp` is different from `std::string` - it is written from back in the early days when strings were terminated with a null - so when it gets to the first trailing null in `hi` it stops looking.

> The reason I used std::ends in the
>   first place is because I've had issues
>   in the past with stringstream
>   retaining garbage data at the end of
>   the stream. std::ends solved that for
>   me.

Sometimes it is a good idea to understand the underlying representation.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a NULL char to HELLO with std::ends. When you initialize hi with str() you are removing the NULL char. The strings are different. strcmp doesn't compare std::strings, it compares char* (it's a C function).

Comment: Gotta love StackOverflow - in the time it took me to write a 2 line answer someone has written War and Peace :-)

Comment: And it appears I was wrong anyway about how str() works. Back to the drawing board for me!

Comment: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/09/programmings-dirtiest-little-secret.html

;)

Comment: That's a great blog!  Thanks for the link! (even though it was mainly posted for 20th Century Boy) :p

Answer (score 0):

std::ends adds a null terminator, (char)'\0'. You'd use it with the deprecated strstream classes, to add the null terminator.

You don't need it with stringstream, and in fact it screws things up, because the null terminator isn't "the special null terminator that ends a string" to stringstream, to stringstream it's just another character, the zeroth character. stringstream just adds it, and that increases the character count (in your case) to seven, and makes the comparison to "hello" fail.

Comment: You don't need it with `strstream` either.  `string::c_str()` always is properly NUL-terminated regardless of how the string was built.

Answer (score 0):

I think to have a good way to compare strings is to use `std::find` method. Do not mix C methods and `std::string` ones!