# Best way to empty stringstream?

Tags: c++, stl, stringstream

One of the possibilities is:

```
somestringstream.str("");
```

But is it most optimal? Is there any way to preserve stringstream internal buffer, so that following operator<<() calls would not require to reserve memory again?

Comment: It was discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I've always done:

```
s.clear();//clear any bits set
s.str(std::string());
```

@litb [gets into more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream/624291#624291) about how to seekp to the start of the stream combined with  std::ends you can keep your allocated size.

Comment: or simply ss.str(""); //more intuitive

Comment: @milan1612:  You would still need to clear the bits, and sending a C-style char* will be slower.

Comment: ..and [this explains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable) why the `s.str(std::string())` variant _could_ be more efficient.