# Convert double to wstring, but wstring must be formatted with scientific notation

Tags: c++, double, string-formatting, wstring

I have a `double` in format `xxxxx.yyyy`, for example `0.001500`.

I would like to convert it into `wstring`, formatted with scientific notation. This is the result I want: `0.15e-2`.

I am not that experienced with C++, so I checked [`std::wstring` reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/) and haven't found any member function that can do this.

I have found [similar threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332111/how-do-i-convert-a-double-into-a-string-in-c) here on Stack Overflow but I just do not know how to apply those answers to solve my problem especially as they do not use `wchar`.

I have tried to solve this myself:

```
// get the value from database as double
double d = // this would give 0.5

// I do not know how determine proper size to hold the converted number 
// so I hardcoded 4 here, so I can provide an example that demonstrates the issue
int len = 3 + 1;  // + 1 for terminating null character
wchar_t *txt = new wchar_t[3 + 1];
memset(txt, L'\0', sizeof(txt));
swprintf_s(txt, 4, L"%e", d);
delete[] txt;
```

I just do not know how to allocate big enough buffer to hold the result of the conversion. Every time I get buffer overflow, and all the answers here from similar thread *estimate* the size. I really would like to avoid this type of introducing "magic" numbers.

I do not know how to use `stringstream` either, because those answers did not convert `double` into `wstring` with *scientific* notation.

All I want is to convert `double` into `wstring`, with resulting `wstring` being formatted with scientific notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::wstringstream` and the `std::scientific` flag to get the output you're looking for as a `wstring`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    double val = 0.001500;
    std::wstringstream str;
    str << std::scientific << val;
    std::wcout << str.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can also set the floating-point precision with additional output flags. Take a look at the [reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/) for more output manipulators you can use. Unfortunately I don't believe your sample expected output is possible since the correct scientific notation would be `1.5e-3`.

Comment: Just one more question: I have to do the conversion for multiple `double`s, can I reuse the same `wstringstream` instead of making new one for every operation? If I can reuse `wstringstream ` can you edit your answer to show me how? Thank you for helping.

Comment: You'll need to clear the stream between uses otherwise the numbers will be appended after each other into the stream. See this SO question for details on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834622/best-way-to-empty-stringstream