# ostringstream and ends

Tags: c++, string, stream

I've been working with somebody else's code and noticed that on all uses of ostringsteam they are in the habit of explicitly appending `std::ends`.

This is something I've never done and have never encountered a problem.

It doesn't appear to, but should `std::ends` make any difference in the following code?

```
ostringstream message;
message << "Hello world, version " << 2 /* << std::ends ??? */;
printf( "%s\n", message.str().c_str() );
```

Comment: Any chance he typo'ed `std::endl`?

Comment: @litb - no I think the intention is definitely ends and it occurs many times

Comment: Your printf is wrong, it is missing a format string.

Comment: @Brian Neal good spot.  Just as well I don't use printf in proper code anymore...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Appending `std::ends` is nonsense here since `stringstream`’s `c_str` returns a null-terminated `char*`. The same was *not* the case for the (now deprecated) `strstream`s where appending `std::ends` was necessary. I believe the author simply didn’t know of this changed behaviour.

Comment: +1 good answer. There are some scenarios for stringstream where `ends` can be useful though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream/624291#624291

Comment: Notwithstanding the above link where ends is useful, they can be hazardous insofar as putting in an "extra" character where none was expected.  My co-worker wondered why his stringstream constructed string was not identically equal to the one from the database, and it was because it had an embedded \0 character.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't, `c_str()` returns NUL-terminated string, anyway.