# How do I use std::ends to overwrite the string in an std::ostringstream?

Tags: c++, string, overwrite, ostringstream

I want to overwrite the string in an `std::ostringstream` but `std::ends` isn't working. Is this a problem with VS2012, or am I doing something wrong? Here is example code:

```
std::ostringstream foo;

foo << "1,2,3,4,5,6";
std::cout << foo.str(); // prints: 1,2,3,4,5,6
foo.clear();
foo.seekp( std::ios_base::beg );
foo << "A,B,C" << std::ends;
std::cout << foo.str(); // prints: A,B,C,4,5,6 NOT just: A,B,C
```

EDIT:

I'm getting a lot of answers that I can use `foo.str( std::string() )` to clear the string... I know that. This question is a spin off from here: [How to reuse an ostringstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream)
I'm trying *not* to reallocate the buffer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367335/ostringstream-and-ends

Comment: Unless `std::ios_base::beg` is `0`, `foo.seekp(std::ios_base::beg)` is wrong. You should do `foo.seekp(0)` instead.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yeah, `std::ios_base::beg` is the 0 element of an `enum`. It's probably an abuse to use that here, 0 would be more correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually it prints

[image]

note the `[NUL]` which corresponds to the `std::ends` and did overwrote the comma after the `3`

the `ostringstream::str()` function returns a container which tracks its length and ignores any possible line ending charakter.

so to get a format which respects the string ending character you can e.g. use the `char *` (or `wchar_t*` if compiling with unicode support) representation obtained via `std::string::c_str()` like this `foo.str().c_str();`

Comment: So maybe the solution would be to dump it to a `const char*`? Like `foo.str().c_str()`?

Comment: @JonathanMee: That's a solution if you want to make things more complicated. It would be simpler to empty the stream before reusing it, rather than messing around with weird C-style idioms.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'd rather avoid reallocing the memory if possible, cause I reuse this stream a lot in code. Though going to a `const char*` is also wasteful. My initial thought on this came from this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream

Comment: @JonathanMee: I'd be surprised if it needed to reallocate the memory after being cleared. It should just reset its internal pointer to the start of its buffer. (But you should check, in the unlikely event that this might be a performance bottleneck).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Because the `std::ostringstream` is in a big loop, yes, the memory is being reallocated with `foo.str( std::string() );`. I just wish that there was a way not to stoop to `foo.str().c_str();`.

Comment: @Valerij If you could update your post to recommend that I use `foo.str().c_str();` I will accept it as that is the best solution that has been presented.

Comment: @JonathanMee you can suggest edits to my answer too. thats how this site works - collaboration and peer reviewing

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `std::ends`?  It is something left over from the days of `std::ostrstream`, where it ensured that the generated `char[]` was null terminated.  You would not normally want to use it on an `std::ostringstream`.

In the code you present, it looks to me like what you really want is two separate `std::ostringstream` (although it is possible to clear the data, by calling `foo.str( "" );`).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to overwrite the string content, simply use the `str(new_string)` method like so:

```
std::ostringstream foo;

foo << "1,2,3,4,5,6";
std::cout << foo.str(); // prints: 1,2,3,4,5,6
// clear just reset error state flags
foo.clear();
// Replace the content of the stream
foo.str("A,B,C");
std::cout << foo.str(); // Should print: A,B,C
```

or:

```
// clear just reset error state flags
foo.clear();
// Clear content of the stream
foo.str("");
foo << "A,B,C";
```

Answer (score 0):

In 3rd statement foo.clear() does not delete the data in foo.
In 4th statement  you used the file position to point begining .
so next statement takes values from begining so the values 1,2,3 are overwritten by A,B,C

instead of foo.clear() use foo.str("");