# What use is there for 'ends' these days?

Tags: c++, stl, ostringstream

I came across a subtle bug a couple of days ago where the code looked something like this:

```
ostringstream ss;
int anInt( 7 );

ss << anInt << "HABITS";
ss << ends;
string theWholeLot = ss.str();
```

The problem was that the `ends` was sticking a '\0' into the `ostringstream` so `theWholeLot` actually looked like `"7HABITS\0"` (i.e. a null at the end)

Now this hadn't shown up because `theWholeLot` was then being used to take the `const char *` portion using `string::c_str()` That meant that the null was masked as it became just a delimiter. However, when this changed to use strings throughout, the null suddenly meant something and comparisons such as:

```
if ( theWholeLot == "7HABITS" )
```

would fail. This got me thinking: Presumably the reason for `ends` is a throwback to the days of `ostrstream` when the stream was not normally terminated with a null and had to be so that `str()` (which then cast out not a `string` but a `char *`) would work correctly.

However, now that it's not possible to cast out a `char *` from a `ostringstream`, using `ends` is not only superfluous, but potentially dangerous and I'm considering removing them all from my clients code.

Can anyone see an obvious reason to use `ends` in a `std::string` only environment?

Comment: My only quibble would be what's a std::string only environment?  Any non-trivial program is going to char* system call arguments, etc.  That said, there are half a dozen other ways to deal with that and ends has negligible usefulness.

Comment: Here is some use of `std::ends`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream/624291#624291

Comment: It's not only for strings. It's useful for general streams. Some unix tools need null bytes as terminators. `cout << ends;` will provide them.

Comment: OK. I guess my point is really that if you have an ostringstream you can get a std::string (but not a null terminated c-string) and if you have a std::string then you can get a null terminated c-string. In other words its actually quite difficult through this route to end up with a string that *isn't* null terminated, but you can end up inadvertently with an unnecessary, unwanted and difficult to detect null ins std::string.

Comment: Thanks for the link Johannes, you're quite right about APIs etc that need nulls in data etc. I think if I was creating such a string I might be tempted to insert the null directly (i.e. '\0' rather than ends) since although they both do the same thing, '\0' does not directly imply an end as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've essentially answered your own question is as much detail that's needed. I certainly can't think of any reason to use `std::ends` when `std::string` and `std::stringstream` handle all that for you.

So, to answer your question explicitly, no, there is no reason to use `std::ends` in a `std::string` only environment.

Comment: I would say there is no reason to use `std::ends` period. I would say I'm a very experienced C++ programmer and yet I didn't even know it existed.

Comment: @Andreas, for having just heard about it the first time, you sound extraordinary sure about it :)

Comment: As Johannes pointed out there are sufficient reasons. Many UNIX programs require the common '\0' terminator, e.g. to pipe text with ASCII characters <= 32 into other programs. I cannot even imagine a life without `find -print0`, `xargs --null` or `read -d '\0'`, just to name a few. Also many APIs require '\0'. It is the common string terminator, and strings are the most important data elements, since anything can be converted into a string. Therefore you want strings to be as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 6):

There are some APIs that expect a "string array" with multiple zero terminated strings, a double zero to mark the end.  Raymond Chang just recently [blogged about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/19/9966131.aspx), most of all to demonstrate how often that this gets fumbled.