# stringstream::ignore(INT_MAX, '\n') causes stream to fail

Tags: c++, stream, stringstream

`stringstream` always seems to fail when I call `stringstream::ignore()`, even if this is done after calling `stringstream::clear()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b;
    stringstream ss;
    string str;
    ifstream inFile("file.txt");
    if(!inFile) {
        cerr << "Fatal: Cannot open input file." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while(getline(inFile, str)) {
        ss << str;                // read string into ss
        ss >> a >> b;             // stream fails trying to store string into int

        ss.clear();               // reset stream state
        assert(ss.good());        // assertion succeeds

        ss.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); // ignore content to next newline
        assert(ss.good());        // assertion fails, why?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`file.txt` contains the following text:

```
123 abc
456 def
```

Why is `ss.good()` false after `ss.ignore()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::endl` outputs `\n` and flushes the stream. However, `stringstream::flush()` is meaningless and does nothing. `flush` only has meaning when the underlying buffer is tied to an output device like the terminal, however, a `stringstream` has nowhere to flush the contents to. If you want to clear the contents of a stringstream do `ss.str("");` instead. However, I would probably change the code to the following:

```
while(getline(inFile, str)) {
    ss.str(str);              // call ss.str() to assign a new string to the stringstream
    if(!ss >> a >> b)         // check if stream fails trying to store string into int
    {
        ss.clear();           // Read failed, so reset stream state
    }
    else
    {
        // Read successful
    }
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Also, if you want to insert a newline into the stringstream, just do `ss << '\n';` and do not call `std::endl`.

Comment: Last sentence: `std::ends` does not put '\n' but '\0'

Comment: A null character could cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: @DragonLord: Yeah, `std::ends` isn't used much anymore (it is leftover from days when `string` and `stringstream` didn't append a null terminator for you). There is a [good question here about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338377/what-use-is-there-for-ends-these-days).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is no newline at the end of `ss`.  After executing the following statements:

```cpp
getline(infile, str);
ss << str;
```

`ss` will not contain a newline character, because `getline()` does not add a newline character to the end of the string stored into the second parameter.  As a result, when this statement is executed:

```cpp
ss.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
```

the stream fails because it reaches the end of the stream without finding a newline character to stop at.

---

`ss.ignore()` is not necessary if `ss.str()` is used to store the string, which replaces the entire contents of the stream.  <s>Should the stream fail, it should be reset and its contents set to the empty string `""`.  Alternatively, `ss.ignore()` could be used, but only as long as a newline character is inserted into the stream immediately after the data is read so that it does not cause the stream to fail—but this would be redundant if the contents of the stream is later set to another value using `ss.str()`.</s>

A successful read of the next line of the file can be ensured by calling `ss.clear()` before the stream is assigned the contents of the next line of the file, since the old contents of the stream are overwritten on `ss.str()`.  The stream state can be reset at the beginning of the loop, and no problems would occur even if the stream fails later in the loop:

```cpp
while(getline(inFile, str)) {
    ss.clear();   // make sure stream is good
    ss.str(str);  // overwrite contents of stream with str
    ss >> a >> b;
    // Even if the stream fails after this line, the stream is reset before each
    // line is stored into the stream, and no problems should occur while reading
    // and parsing subsequent lines in the file.

    // Code to validate and store data from file...
}
```

Comment: `flush()` does nothing for `stringstream`, also no need to use `endl` or `ignore`, see my answer.

Comment: Looks better. Also, instead of calling `ss.clear()` every loop, I would do `if(!ss >> a >> b) ss.clear();` so it is only called when the stream fails (I changed my answer also to reflect this).