# How can I free ostringstream?

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
int n=2;
ostringstream convert;   // stream used for the conversion
convert << n; 
string query= convert.str();
```

How can I free ostringstream?

Comment: reduplicate question？ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288036/how-to-clear-ostringstream ？

Comment: @bystander: What's that weird question mark? Are you making a homograph attack?

Comment: @KerrekSB I just can't  make sure user2036891's meaning...

Comment: Put it in a separate function, or use `std::to_string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With lifetime management:

```
std::string query;
int n = 2;

{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << n;
    query = oss.str();
}
```

Shorter, but a bit tougher to read:

```
int n = 2;
std::string query
          = static_cast<std::ostringstream &>(std::ostringstream() << n).str();
```

Possibly better, depending on your situation:

```
auto query = std::to_string(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let it go out of scope:

```
int n=2;
string query;
{
    ostringstream convert;
    convert << n;
    query = convert.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to free the stream. the stream is on the stack, so it will destroyed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I free ostringstream?

If by "free" you mean "deallocate resources" for the instance, then let it go out of scope.

```
int n=2;
string query;
{
    ostringstream convert;   // stream used for the conversion
    convert << n; 
    qyuery = convert.str();
}
```

If you mean "clear the contents" then you can use:

```
int n=2;
ostringstream convert;   // stream used for the conversion
convert << n; 
string query1 = convert.str();
// clear the contents & reset error bits (thanks @PeterWood)
convert.str("");
convert.clear();
convert << n + 1;
string query2 = convert.str();
```