# for loop with iterators producing the wrong results c++

Tags: c++, unix, g++

I am creating a HTML file that creates a Google map of a object called Quake which contains Latitude, Longitude, Magnitude and Depth. Another class called QuakeData is a class that creates a vector of Quake objects.

A function below takes the vector of objects, and gets the details of them (Latitude, Longitude and Magnitude) and then outputs them into the HTML in this format:

```
[58.678, -151.887, 'M2.6'],
```

Where the first number is the Latitude, the second is the Longitude, and the third is the Magnitude, in the format shown.

Here is the loop that I currently have, which extracts the Latitude, Longitude and Magnitude using getters:

```
double mag;
double lat;
double lon;
string complete;
ostringstream out;
vector<Quake>::const_iterator i;
for (i = quakes.begin(); i != quakes.end(); i++)
{
    mag = i->getMagnitude();
    lat = i->getLatitude();
    lon = i->getLongitude();

    out << "[" << lat << ", " << lon << ", 'M" << mag << "'],";
    complete = out.str();
    outfile << complete << endl;
}
```

However this produces a result like this:

```
[58.678, -151.887, 'M2.6'], (end of line)
[58.678, -151.887, 'M2.6'],[33.92, -117.08, 'M2.9'],(end of line)
[58.678, -151.887, 'M2.6'],[33.92, -117.08, 'M2.9'],[-3.203, 142.864, 'M4.7'],(end of line)
```

What I want is:

```
[58.678, -151.887, 'M2.6'],(end of line)
[33.92, -117.08, 'M2.9'],(end of line)
[-3.203, 142.864, 'M4.7'],(end of line)
```

What exactly is wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each loop appends new data to the existing stream: move the declaration inside the loop so it's using a new instance for each line.

```
for (i = quakes.begin(); i != quakes.end(); i++)
{
  ostringstream out;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear your ostringstream  between iterations. Use `out.str(""); out.clear();` (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288036/how-to-clear-ostringstream) for an explanation).

Answer (score 1):

```
complete = out.str();
out.str("");
```

Answer (score 0):

As people have pointed out you either need to reset the `ostringstream` or reduce its scope.

A more idiomatic and efficient way to write your code is to extract the code for outputing a `Quake` to an `ostream`, and then use standard algorithms to `copy` it to your output stream directly, without needing an intermediate `ostringstream`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Quake& quake) {
    os << "["
       << quake.getLatitude() << ", "
       << quake.getLongitude() << ", "
       << "'M" << quake.getMagnitude()
       << "']";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    vector<Quake> quakes;
    ofstream outfile("quakes.txt");

    copy(quakes.begin(), quakes.end()
        ostream_iterator<Quake>(outfile, ",\n"));
}
```