# stringstream string to int

Tags: c++

The C++ code below does `int` to `string` and a `string` to `int` conversions. Then, it repeats these steps again. The `stringstream` to `int` line `stream1 >> i3;`  is breaking the code.  What am I missing here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int i1 = 101;
 int i2 = 202;
 int i3 = 0;
 string s1 = "";
 string s2 = "";
 stringstream stream1;

 for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
 {

   //int to string
   stream1.str("");
   cout << "i1 " << i1 << endl;
   stream1 << i1;
   s1 = stream1.str();
   cout << "s1 " << s1 << endl;

   //int to string
   cout << "i2 " << i2 << endl;
   stream1.str("");
   stream1 << i2;
   s2 = stream1.str();
   cout << "s2 " << s2 << endl;

   //string to int
   stream1.str("");
   stream1.str(s2);
   stream1 >> i3;
   //line above causes s1 and s2 to get messed up during 2nd time in for loop
   cout << "i3-- " << i3 << endl;

  }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you flip the `>>` to a `<<`?what output are you trying to get, I am not sure I follow.

Comment: Abhay, your codepad link output is just like what I get.  s1 and s2 should not be empty.  If you comment out the stream1 >> i3 line you will see that s1 and s2 are 101 and 202

Comment: @user584583: Sorry. yes, that should not be empty.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tested your code and could reproduce the problem. I solved it inserting a .clear() before .str("")

Have a look here: [How to reuse an ostringstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int i1 = 101;
 int i2 = 202;
 int i3 = 0;
 string s1 = "";
 string s2 = "";
 stringstream stream1;

 for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
 {

   //int to string
   stream1.clear();
   stream1.str("");
   cout << "i1 " << i1 << endl;
   stream1 << i1;
   s1 = stream1.str();
   cout << "s1 " << s1 << endl;

   //int to string
   cout << "i2 " << i2 << endl;
   stream1.clear();
   stream1.str("");
   stream1 << i2;
   s2 = stream1.str();
   cout << "s2 " << s2 << endl;

   //string to int
   stream1.clear();
   stream1.str("");
   stream1.str(s2);
   stream1 >> i3;
   //line above causes s1 and s2 to get messed up during 2nd time in for loop
   cout << "i3-- " << i3 << endl;

  }
  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that the stream's EOF flag is being set while extracting the integer (i.e. `stream1.eof()` returns `true`), but you never clear it. Inserting a call to `stream1.clear()` after extraction fixes your issue.

Answer (score 4):

After reading `i3` from the stream, the eof bit of the stream gets set. This is because reading an integer from the stream makes the stream read until either it reads a nondigit character or it runs out of characters to read. When the latter that happens, the eof bit is set.

For example, I can change this line,

```
stream1.str(s2);
```

to this,

```
stream1.str(s2 + " ");
```

so when `stream1 >> i3;` is executed, it will encounter a nondigit character (' '), stop reading and not set the eof bit.

You have to unset the eof bit by `.clear` or some other method before attempting to read from it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a C guy most of the day, so I would simply use `atoi()` do to the conversion:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // header for atoi()

//stream1 >> i3;  // replace this for the line below
i3 = atoi(stream1.str().c_str());

cout << "i3-- " << i3 << endl;
```

What I'm doing is retrieving a `std::string` from the `stringstream`, and from that, getting a `const char*` to be used as argument for `atoi()`, which converts a *C string* to an integer.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: This is not quite correct. If you get data out from the stringstream into a string `s3` rather than the int `i3`, the same problem occurs. `stringstream` basically has to be reset with `clear()` after data is extracted from it -- regardless of any conversion of the data you extract.

Comment: I do this all the time without needing to call `clear()`.  The call to `stream1.str()` gets information out of the stream without changing the status flags on the stream ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/str/ ).

Comment: Well I suppose I could paste the entire source code of the application so you guys can test it, but since the code only has 2 changes on the original source code, I think it's not really necessary. Rest assured that this method was tested and works.

Comment: C++ guys don't like C answers.. is that enough reason for the downvotes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871711/atoi-how-to-identify-the-difference-between-zero-and-error

Comment: The downvotes are because while it "fixes" the problem. It doesn't explain why/how what the problem even was in the first place. So while it might fix the immediate issue, it's not very helpful for learning.