# atoi — how to identify the difference between zero and error?

Tags: c, atoi

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

#### Return Value

On success, the function returns the converted integral number as an `int` value.
**If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned.**
If the correct value is out of the range of representable values, INT_MAX or INT_MIN is returned.

So how I differ between `atoi("poop")` and `atoi("0")` and `atoi("0000000")`

Yes I *can* loop and check for all zeroes in case I get 0 result, but isn't there a better way?

**Notice: I use ANSI C89**

Comment: [cplusplus.com is wrong](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/cplusplus.com) about `atoi`, it does not detect errors at all. Don't trust that site.

Comment: The C89, C99 and C11 standards say nothing about the value returned by `atoi()` when the correct value is out of range.  The C++11 standard says even less (it lists `atoi` in two tables, and that's all!).  The statements from http://cplusplus.com/ are essentially wishful thinking and/or common implementations — not guaranteed by any standard.

Comment: TL;DR: Use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi instead.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That's one of the reasons `atoi` is sometimes considered unsafe. Use `strtol` / `strtoul` instead. And if you have it use [`strtonum`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strtonum).

The function `atoi` is more dangerous than you might think. [The `POSIX` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html) says:

> If the value cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined.

The C99 standard says this also:

> 7.20.1
>
> The functions atof, atoi, atol, and atoll need not affect the value of
> the integer expression errno on an error. If the value of the result
> cannot be represented, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Comment: Doesn't answer the headline question.

Comment: @BeeOnRope edit queue is full. Answer is: "It's undefined, so you cannot reliably determine the difference"

Answer (score 20):

As described by @cnicutar and @ouah, `atoi` can't distinguish a valid 0 from an invalid string making  the `strtol` family better options.

But **Why?** and **How?** First understand that both `atoi` and `strtol` only convert the initial set of numbers in a string to numeric values. Any trailing non-numeric characters are simply ignored. `strtol` can be used to check for invalid strings because in addition to a numeric value, it also returns a pointer to the end of the numeric portion of the string. Thus if this `end` pointer still refers to the start of the original string, you can tell that there was an error and no characters from the string were converted.

There are a few of other subtleties, as seen in the code example:

```
long lnum;
int num;
char *end;

errno = 0;

lnum = strtol(in_str, &end, 10);        //10 specifies base-10
if (end == in_str)     //if no characters were converted these pointers are equal
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: can't convert string to number\n");

//If sizeof(int) == sizeof(long), we have to explicitly check for overflows
if ((lnum == LONG_MAX || lnum == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE)  
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: number out of range for LONG\n");

//Because strtol produces a long, check for overflow
if ( (lnum > INT_MAX) || (lnum < INT_MIN) )
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: number out of range for INT\n");

//Finally convert the result to a plain int (if that's what you want)
num = (int) lnum;
```

Note: If you are sure the input string will be within the valid int range, you can eliminate `lnum` and simply cast strtol's return directly: `num = (int) strtolen(in_str, &end, 10);`

Comment: There's a lot that's good there, but...if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`, you haven't detected overflow.  You should set `errno = 0;` before calling `strtol()`, and then you need to test for `((lnum == LONG_MAX || lnum == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE)` to spot overflow.  Although it does the job, `strtol()` is actually very hard to use correctly — even harder than you demonstrate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Great point. I have updated my answer accordingly, Thanks.

Comment: Concerning `if ( (lnum > INT_MAX) || (lnum < INT_MIN) )`, for symmetry  with `long` overflow, that `if()` block should also `errno = ERANGE;` and set the `lnum` to `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot.

`atoi` cannot detect errors. If the result cannot be represented, `atoi` invokes undefined behavior.  Use `strtol` instead of `atoi`.

Secure CERT coding advises to use `strtol` instead of `atoi`, read:

[INT06-C. Use strtol() or a related function to convert a string token to an integer](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT06-C.+Use+strtol()+or+a+related+function+to+convert+a+string+token+to+an+integer)