# Input validation of an Integer using atoi()

Tags: c, validation, input, numbers, integer

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char buffer[20];
    int num;

    printf("Please enter a number\n");
    fgets(buffer, 20, stdin);
    num = atoi(buffer);

    if(num == '\0')
    {
        printf("Error Message!");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("\n\nThe number entered is %d", num);
    }

    getchar();
}
```

The above code accepts a number in the form of a string and converts it to integer using atoi.  If the user inputs a decimal number, only the bit before the decimal is accepted.  Moreover, if the user enters a letter, it returns 0.

Now, I have two queries:

i) I want the program to detect if the user entered a number with decimal point and output an error message.  I don't want it to take the part before the decimal point.  I want it to recognize that the input is invalid.

ii) If atoi returns 0 in case there are letters, how can I validate it since the user can enter the number 0 as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871711/atoi-how-to-identify-the-diffrence-between-zero-and-error

Comment: What do you want? To make sure the user inputs an whole number or to know if the user inputs a floating number? -- Check ctype.h. It has some functions isnumber(), isdigit() and so on.

Comment: `printf( "Error message" )` is *always* wrong.  You meant `fprintf( stderr, "Error message" )`.  Errors belong on `stderr`.  `stdout` is for output.

Comment: And again, the return type of `main` is `int`, not `void`.

Comment: @Sascha Yes, I want to know if the user inputs a whole number

Comment: @larsmans Oops.  I forgot to correct it.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`atoi` is not suitable for error checking. Use `strtol` or `strtoul` instead.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

long int result;
char *pend;

errno = 0;
result = strtol (buffer, &pend, 10);

if (result == LONG_MIN && errno != 0) 
{
  /* Underflow. */
}

if (result == LONG_MAX && errno != 0) 
{
  /* Overflow. */
}

if (*pend != '\0') 
{
    /* Integer followed by some stuff (floating-point number for instance). */
}
```

Comment: "not very sutiable" is a *huge* understatement!

Comment: @WilliamPursell: More security, more work, more code! You won't get around it. Putting a wrapper around it shrinks it back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `isdigit` function that can help you check each character:

```
#include <ctype.h>

/* ... */

for (i=0; buffer[i]; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(buffer[i])) {
            printf("Bad\n");
            break;
        }
}
```