# atoi giving wrong result for alpha decimal strings

Tags: c

I am trying to call atoi() on the following strings: "54" and "54df4". While the first input gave me the correct result of 54, the call on second string also gave me the result of 54. I assume that the function is converting the string to decimal as far as possible; instead, it should not convert at all.
Why is this so? The following is my code:

```
cout << "Wrong: " << atoi("54df4") << endl;
```

Thanks,Rakesh.

Comment: What makes you think it should behave any differently?

Comment: Thank you all for the pointers - I am just curious as to why it is defined to work partially. It shouldn't process such mixed strings right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how `atoi` is specified to work. If you don't want to convert strings containing non-digit characters you have to pre-scan the string, or use a function such as [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) which can give back the location of the first non-digit character:

```
cons char *number = "54df4";
char *endp = NULL;

int value = strtol(number, &endp, 10);

if (endp != NULL && endp < (number + strlen(number)))
{
    printf("Stopped scanning in middle of string, it contains non-digit characters\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation of atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

> The string can contain additional characters after those that form the
>   integral number, which are ignored and have no effect on the behavior
>   of this function.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how `atoi` is defined. Taking [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) man page for instance:

> The `atoi()` function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by `nptr` to `int`.

Or in C standard:

> #### C11 (n1570), § 7.22.1.2 The `atoi`, `atol`, and `atoll` functions
>
> The `atoi`, `atol`, and `atoll` functions convert the initial portion of the string pointed to by nptr to `int`, `long int`, and `long long int` representation, respectively.

- If you want to do complexer operations on the string to convert, use `strtol` instead (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15229434/1126268) for instance).
- If you don't agree with these specifications, write your own function!

Answer (score 1):

From the following somewhat arbitrarily found man page for atoi....

http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi

**The atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by nptr to int. **

In short, the function is working exactly as it is defined.