# Computing Minimum, Maximum, and Average Test Score Input Validation

Tags: c, max, min

hey guys I have an assignment in programming in c which says :

"  Write a C program that inputs a list of integer test scores
between 0 and 100, and computes the maximum score, the minimum
score, and the average score. Use -1, as a sentinel, to mark the end of the
input. Reject any test score outside the range 0 to 100. Your program
should also detect and reject faulty input, such as letters and characters.
You should have a function that reads and validates an input test score
and rejects invalid and faulty input. Here is a sample run "

I wrote a code but my problem is how to reject input like characters ..:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define sentinel -1     // to end the program

int main ()
{
    int status, score, sum, i, max, min;
    double avrg;
    i = 0;          /* the counter */
    sum = 0;            // the total scores
    printf (" Enter the score , %d to termenate > ", sentinel);
    status = scanf ("%d", &score);  // checking the validity of the input

    max = score;        // the initial maximum
    min = score;        // the initial minimum

    while (score != sentinel) {

        while (score < 0 || score > 100)    // no negative or more than 100 score

        {
            printf ("The number is out of the range ; try again> ");
            scanf ("%d", &score);
        }

        sum = sum + score;
        i = i + 1;
        printf (" Enter the score , %d to termenate > ", sentinel);
        status = scanf ("%d", &score);
        if (score > max && score < 100)
            max = score;
        if (score < min && score > 0)
            min = score;
    }

    if (i != 0) {
        avrg = (double) sum / i;    // the sum of scores over the number of scores
        printf (" The avarage is : \n %.2f ", avrg);
        printf ("\n");
        printf (" Maximum score is : \n %d", max);
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("Minmum score is : \n %d", min);
    } else          // when the user ends the program without entering any value
    {
        printf ("You didn't enter any score");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: Please format the code with the right indentation. You are not checking every value

Comment: `scanf` with `%d` returns 0 if an invalid input(like characters) was entered. So, if `status` is 0, `scanf` failed. Therefore, you must Clear the `stdin` and prompt the user again until a valid input is entered.

Answer (score 1):

When using `scanf` for multiple inputs, there are several conditions you have to watch out for. Those are `matching` failures and `read` failures. Checking the `scanf` return allows you to identify both. In the case of accepting repeated integer input in a while loop, if matching failure occurs, you must also insure that you empty `stdin` to prevent an endless loop. There are several approaches, but the most straight forward with integer input is to simply use `getchar` to read all `chars` from `stdin` before using `scanf` again.

Below is a quick example of your code implementing this approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>     /* for INT_MAX */

#define SENTINEL -1     /* value to end the program         */
#define MAXSCORE 100    /* max input for score allowed      */

int main ()
{
    int status = 0;     /* always initialize you variables  */
    int score = 0;
    size_t sum = 0;     /* size_t for non-negative numbers  */
    size_t idx = 1;
    size_t max = 0;
    size_t min = INT_MAX;
    double avrg = 0.0;
    int c = 0;

    printf ("\n Enter scores [ '%d' to end entry ]\n", SENTINEL);

    while (printf ("\n  score: ") && (status = scanf ("%d", &score)) != -1)
    {
        /* check for matching failure, empty input buffer */
        if (status == 0) do { c = getchar(); } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF);

        if (score == SENTINEL) break;
        if (score > MAXSCORE || score < 0) continue;

        if (score > max) max = score;
        if (score < min) min = score;

        sum += score;
        avrg = (double)sum/idx++;

        printf ("\n    minimum : %3zu\n    maximum : %3zu\n    average : %.2f\n", min, max, avrg);
    }

    printf ("\n Input complete\n\n");

    if (idx > 1)
        printf ("  number of scores : %3zu    Max score : %3zu    Min score : %3zu    Avg : %.2f\n\n",
                idx - 1, max, min, avrg);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/grades

 Enter scores [ '-1' to end entry ]

  score: 77

    minimum :  77
    maximum :  77
    average : 77.00

  score: 88

    minimum :  77
    maximum :  88
    average : 82.50

  score: 83

    minimum :  77
    maximum :  88
    average : 82.67

  score: -88

  score: 108

  score: G

  score: -1

 Input complete

  number of scores :   3    Max score :  88    Min score :  77    Avg : 82.67
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get input as a string first, and then check for invalid characters using strtol?

Such as the answer in [Input validation of an Integer using atoi()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229411/input-validation-of-an-integer-using-atoi)