# What's the easiest way to prevent a user from entering a letter when the program asks for a number?

Tags: string, floating-point, int, cin

Say I have a float variable called "varFloat" and I use cin to allow the user to input a number, how can I prevent the user from entering a letter?

I have a calculator program that breaks if a letter is entered instead of a number.

```
        cout << "Enter num1: ";
        cin >> num1;
        cin.ignore(); 

        do
        {
            //Select function
            cout << "Enter a function ('+' '-' '*' '/'):";
            getline(cin, function);

            if (function == "+" || function == "-" || function == "*" || function == "/")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << function << " IS AN INVALID FUNCTION" << endl;
            }
        } while (function != "+" || function != "-" || function != "*" || function != "/");
```

If a letter is entered for num1, the program seems to skip the getline and prints " IS AN INVALID FUNCTION" endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I prevent the user from entering a letter?

Code cannot.  There is no magic arm to slap the user's hand as an attempt to enter <kbd>A</kbd> happens.

Instead, form a helper function, not simply `cin >> num1;`, to accept a *line* of input, parse it for correctness and report results.  There are 3 results: input is acceptable, input is not acceptable yet `cin` is still open, input is not acceptable and `cin` is closed.

Perhaps expand the helper function to discard unacceptable input and re-prompt when `cin` is still open.

For `float`, I do this in C with code such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211144/2410359) which employs `strtof()` to parse and provide an end-of-parsing location.