# How does SPIM deal with incorrect types when reading from console?

Tags: assembly, mips, simulator, system-calls, spim

I'm creating a MIPS simulator, and have come across a point that I think has multiple solutions. SPIM simulates reads from the console with syscall operations. I have used SPIM before but currently do not have access to it. How does it deal with incorrect types when reading from the console? For instance, if you do a syscall for read_int, and enter "asdf" and then press enter, what happens? What should happen? SPIM references suggest that it reads an integer from the line, and ignores anything after the integer, which is simply just a regex match for the first sequence of digits. What happens when there are non-digits first, then digits, then more non digits? What about no digits at all?

I don't wish to recreate SPIM, and figured I would get recommendations from the community on how they would like a MIPS simulator to perform when given the wrong type of input.

Some possible inputs to think about:
1234 (correct)
a1234 (what should this do?)
a1234b (what should this do?)
ab (what should this do?)
 (what should simply pressing enter do?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, I checked the `spim` [sourcecode](http://sourceforge.net/p/spimsimulator/code/HEAD/tree/). It wasn't that big so it was pretty easy to find [syscall.c](http://sourceforge.net/p/spimsimulator/code/HEAD/tree/CPU/syscall.c) which says that the `READ_INT_SYSCALL` is implemented using `atol`.

The documentation on `atol` can be found [anywhere on the internet](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atol) or in your systems manual, but for the sake of completeness:

> Description
>
> The atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by nptr to int. The behavior is the same as
>
> strtol(nptr, NULL, 10); 
>   except that atoi() does not detect errors.
>
> The atol() and atoll() functions behave the same as atoi(), except that they convert the initial portion of the string to their return type of long or long long. atoq() is an obsolete name for atoll().
>
> Return Value
>
> The converted value.

I realize that doesn't really answer your question, because it turns out the behaviour of atoi is more or less undefined. You can see the POSIX Standard [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html) where it says that "*If the value cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined*" or see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871711/atoi-how-to-identify-the-difference-between-zero-and-error).