# How do you clear a std::ostringstream instance so it can be reused?

Tags: c++, string, std, stringstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reuse an ostringstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream)

I have been using `std::ostringstream` to convert `float` and `int` values to strings but I cannot find anyway to reuse an instance. To illustrate what I mean here is the following along with the methods that I have tried to use to clear the stream

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <sstream>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
   ostringstream stream;
   stream << "Test";
   cout << stream.str() << endl;  
   stream.flush();                
   stream << "----";
   cout << stream.str() << endl; 
   stream.clear();
   stream << "****";
   cout << stream.str() << endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

generates output

```
 Test
 Test----
 Test----****
```

This is giving me a problem as I am having to create many instances of `ostringstream` which is wasteful. Clearly `clear()` and `flush()` do not do what I need so is there a way to do this? I checked the documentation at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/ but there is nothing there that appears to do what I need. Is there a way to reset or clear the stream??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `stream.str("");` to make the underlying string an empty one. Better yet, don't reuse objects. In C++ the philosophy is to make an object when you need it and dispose of it when you're done:

```
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << 10;
    std::cout << oss.str();
}

{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << 20.5;
    std::cout << oss.str();
}
```

Or better yet:

```
std::cout << static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << 10).str();
```

Comment: +1: Was about to say the exact same thing.  Although doing `stream.str("");` always felt like a hack to me.

Comment: Generally agree with your post except for the part that starts with *Or better yet:* and the rest that follows.  You couldn't possibly think that is **better**, would you?!

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps: It's just an example. Of course you could write `std::cout << 10` and be done with it. If I needed a string, I'd say `std::to_string(10)`, I suppose.

Comment: There's no such thing as "philosophy in C++ to make an object when you need it and dispose when you're done" and there has never been. Using the str("") call is the perfect way of "resetting" the stringstream. It's rather your hint to use static_cast, that is generally predicted to never be used in the application code, a counter-C++-philosopy thing.

Answer (score 11):

`clear()` only clears the error flags.  This is a common mistake.  You want to call `str()`, and pass it an empty string to clear the buffer:

```
stream.str("");
```

will do what you want.