# error with std::ostringsteam and std::string

Tags: c++

Hi i want to save many different csv files from a function with a naming convention based on a  different double value. I do this with a for loop and pass a string value to save each .csv file differently. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do the desired result would be

```
1.1_file.csv
1.2_file.csv
```

but instead i get

```
1.1_file.csv
1.11.2_file.csv
```

Here is a working sample code, what can i do to fix this

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::string file = "_file.csv";
    std::string s;
    std::ostringstream os;
    double x;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        x = 0.1 + 0.1 *i;
        os << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);
        os << x;
        s = os.str();
        std::cout<<s+file<<std::endl;
        s.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: whats the random downvote for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ostringstream` doesn't reset on each iteration of the loop, so you are just adding `x` to it every iteration; put it inside the scope of the `for` to make `os` be a different clean object on each iteration, or reset the contents with `os.str("")`.

Also, the variable `s` is unnecessary; you can just do

```
std::cout << os.str() + file << std::endl;
```

And you don't need `s` and you eliminate the overhead of making a copy of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Your ostringstream is getting appended for each iteration of the loop. You should clear it and reuse it as shown below (courtesy: [How to reuse an ostringstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream) on how to reuse an `ostringstream`)

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::string file = "_file.csv";
    std::string s;

    double x;
    std::ostringstream os;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        x = 0.1 + 0.1 * i;
        os << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1);
        os << x;
        s = os.str();
        std::cout << s + file << std::endl;
        os.clear();
        os.str("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SethCarnegie, may be, I just tried to convey that `os` should be local to the `for` loop.

Comment: Oh yeah oops, I thought you added it. I will remove my comment.