# How to print all possible unique bit masks of unsigned long long?

Tags: c++, string, hex, string-formatting, stringstream

Having an `unsigned long long` how to print it in form of its `hex` mask into `std::string`?

I tried to iterate over binary (values like `0001`, `0010`, `0100`) mask:

```
std::stringstream str;
std::string result;
for (unsigned long long mask = 1; mask != 0; mask <<= 1) {
    str << mask;
    str >> result;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    str.flush();
}
```

yet I see only values `==` `1` (see [live sample here](http://ideone.com/eOh9DY)).

So I wonder how to print all possible unique bit masks of `unsigned long long`?

Comment: You're after ALL of them?

Comment: so you just want those with exactly one bit set to 1, right?

Comment: @jrok: yes I am (after all that contain only one `1` while all other digits are `0` in binary representation)

Comment: This [less complex version](http://ideone.com/wKV7hu) works fine for me.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: yet how to put it into string?

Comment: @DuckQueen I didn't get it immediately, I thought you wanted to iterate over all possible values. Silly me :)

Comment: @DuckQueen: With `std::to_string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `str.clear()`, not `str.flush()`. And see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer) for the hex part

Answer (score 1):

> *Having an `unsigned long long` how to print it in form of its `hex` mask into `std::string`?*

You need to use [`std::hex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/) for printing numbers in hexadecimal base and also note that to reuse the `stringstream` object you actually need to clear its content by using `str()` method and also clear the error state flags by calling [`clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream str;
    std::string result;
    for (unsigned long long mask = 1; mask != 0; mask <<= 1)
    {
        // retrieve the string:
        str << std::hex << mask;
        str >> result;
        std::cout << result << std::endl;

        // clear the stringstream:
        str.clear();
        str.str(std::string());
    }
}
```

See [How to reuse an ostringstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/624260/1168156) :)

Answer (score 0):

every value of a unsigned long long is unique.
so iterate over it and have a look at this question
[Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

**[Edit]**
Ah I see you only want values with one bit set. Ok do not iterate, shift through it.