# use of ss.str("") after ss.clear() for a newly defined string stream

Tags: c++

(Learning C++) I have been looking at code portion below:

```
stringstream ss;

// more code 

ss.clear();
ss.str("");
```

Why is `ss.str("");` called when `ss.clear();` is meant to remove the string value? I printed out the `str()` value to `std::cout` and saw that it had length zero without the line `ss.str("");` so why is it included?

In my research, I ran into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624260/how-to-reuse-an-ostringstream/624291#624291) and the accepted answer by @Johannes Schaub - litb does the same thing. What am I missing out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear

Comment: `ss.clear()` doesn't do what you think it does, whereas `ss.str("")` does "clear" the stringstream buffer data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::stringstream::clear()` is inherited from a parent class, and the inheritage source function is [`std::basic_ios::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)

From CppReference (linked above):

> Sets the stream error state flags by assigning them the value of state. By default, assigns `std::ios_base::goodbit` which has the effect of clearing all error state flags.

It does **not** clear the content of the `stringstream`, but all bad flags that were set in previous I/O operations (like encountering EOF).

The actual statement that clears the string content is `ss.str("")`.

This example demonstrates what `clear()` does:

```
using std::cout;
std::istringstream s("8");
int a;
s >> a;
cout << a; // Output: 8
a = 10;
s >> a;
cout << a << " " << s.eof(); // Output: 10 1
s.clear();
cout << s.eof() << " " << s.str(); // Output: 0 8
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is ss.str(""); called when ss.clear(); is meant to remove the string value?

`clear()` is not meant to remove the string value.It is meant to set the stream state flags.

```
stringstream ss;
ss<<1;
cout<<ss.str()<<endl; //prints 1
ss.clear();           // does not remove value from ss
cout<<ss.str()<<endl; //prints 1 
ss.str("");           //this removes the value
cout<<ss.str();       //empty
```