# What is the type of the following?

Tags: c++

```
typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t,          std::char_traits<wchar_t>, TestStringAllocator<wchar_t> >       TestString;
```

So is it a "basic_string" or is it a "wchar_t"

Please let me understand, I need to do conversions and don't know what the type of TestString is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `TestString` is just `std::wstring` with custom allocator defined `TestStringAllocator`.

Most probably this is used to inspect how allocator works and how std::basic_string is using that.
Some time ago I used something similar to [investigate if `std::string_stream` is optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52011246/1387438) (is not).

Since you didn't provided definition of `TestStringAllocator` it is impossible to tell what is its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the code says, the type of `TestString` is:

```
std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, TestStringAllocator<wchar_t>>
```

It's a string, not a character.

Comment: So is it a basic_string or a wchar_t? What does everything in <> mean?

Comment: It's a string **of** `wchar_t`. Used by folk who haven't embraced the beauty of UTF-8 yet ;-) Informally you can think of it as a "Unicode" string, but that term is not really particularly helpful.

Comment: @Bob : *What does everything in <> mean?* Those are [template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates)