# How to clear stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

```
stringstream parser;

parser << 5;
short top = 0;
parser >> top;
parser.str(""); //HERE I'M RESETTING parser

parser << 6; //DOESN'T PUT 6 INTO parser
short bottom = 0;
parser >> bottom;
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Typically to 'reset' a stringstream you need to both reset the underlying sequence to an empty string with `str` and to clear any fail and eof flags with `clear`.

```
parser.str( std::string() );
parser.clear();
```

Typically what happens is that the first `>>` reaches the end of the string and sets the eof bit, although it successfully parses the first short. Operations on the stream after this immediately fail because the stream's eof bit is still set.

Comment: yes, it sets eof after operator>>() has been used and sometimes eof can set fail as well. Thanks

Comment: Personally I think `parser.str("")` is clearer, but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Might be worth editing this answer to put parser.clear() first, as other methods of adding content to the stream (e.g. parser << 5) don't work unless clear is called first.

Comment: @T.E.D. , I think it is a bit more efficient this way, since you avoid calling string constructor on a `const char *`

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi - There are some cases, particularly those involving things that are inherently slow like resizing/destructing dynamically allocated containers, where it would be the height of folly to do the less clear thing for the sake of some theoretical micro-optimization.

Comment: `parser.str({});`