# 'itoa' : function does not take 1 arguments & 'c' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, string, itoa

I've been trying for 2 days now to get this code to work. It's just been error after error.

Can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int h = 0;
    for(int a = 100; a<1000; a++)
        for(int b = 100; b<1000; b++)
            int c = a * b;
// Error: "c" is undefined
            if ((c == reverse(c)) && (c > h))
                h = c;
    cout << "The answer is: " << h << endl;
}

int reverse (int x)
{
// Error: "'itoa' : function does not take 1 arguments"
    string s = string(itoa(x));
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
  return (x);
}
```

Using std::to_string just gives me more errors as well.

Comment: Listen to your compiler. It's telling you what the problem is. `...does not take 1 arguments...`, that is telling you one of two things: 1. You're sending one argument to a function that doesn't take any arguments(highly unlikely in this situation), or 2. You're sending one argument when the function takes at least two, but could be `n(Arg)`. If `n=100` and you sent `99` it'd say `...function does not take 99 arguments'.

Comment: `..function does not take 99 arguments...`. The same goes when you exceed it, saying the same thing! It will compile correctly when you send it the correct amount of arguments.

Comment: By looking at your code further, and your continued frustration in comments to other answers, I would suggest that you utilize braces even when they're not "needed"! Especially if you get simple errors continually. When you can bust out code while watching Seinfield, then omit them. I use 'em like it's required!

Comment: Perhaps you should ask about how to address the problems you were having with [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), it's 14 times better than itoa, and standard.

Comment: Just FYI: In a situation where you have one or more programmer(you) defined  overloaded functions which accept `n (+/-) x` arguments you wouldn't get that error message, but could possibly get unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your compiler explains something to you in an error message, you should believe it. `itoa` does, in fact, take more than one argument, as you can see at the following link:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/

Edit: Oh and this is achievable using standard, C++-style code by the way (fixed a bit of code as per suggestion in the comments):

```
int reverse(int x)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << x;

    std::string s = ss.str();
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());

    ss.clear();
    ss.str(s.c_str());

    ss >> x;

    return x;
}
```

Here. Not sure it's the cleanest solution but it works on my compiler.

Edit: Found out how to use only one stringstream here : [How to clear stringstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848087/how-to-clear-stringstream)

Comment: "Error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::stringstream" to "std::string" exists" and a few more errors :/

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I am not denying this though in fixing my own solution I did not want to copy yours. If people find yours better they can upvote it (it is indeed shorter).

Comment: I just tested your solution and it does not appear to be working (no reversing) while this one does. I wonder if it's possible to use only one stringstream though. I had no luck with clear() or flush() emptying it so I had to resort to using one for input and the other for output.

Comment: "'void std::reverse(_BidIt,_BidIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided", "'reverse' : local function definitions are illegal", "(7): this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched", "end of file found before the left brace '{'". I think c++ hates me lol.

Comment: It compiles fine and works on my computer. What compiler / IDE are you using ? Can you link us to your code via http://pastebin.com/ ?

Comment: Again listen to compiler! Search the line the error references and look to see what might match the error msg. `end of file found before left brace..` means exactly that.

Comment: +1 You're missing a closing brace for the main function which you could have spotted very easily with better indentation.

Comment: Okay sorry. Now it's giving me "'<<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect" errors. and ss_in and ss_out has a "incomplete type is not allowed" error.

Comment: Try using the latest code I have put there (sorry for the many edits, been trying to figure out the best way to do this).

Comment: Oh and you are not including sstream in which are stringstreams located.

Comment: @Leinad177: You were missing a couple of `#include` statements and a prototype for the `reverse` function. I fixed those and the code works correctly on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ZFjLT).

Comment: @Blastfurnace That works, thanks :) And thanks everyone else for helping.

Comment: @Leinad177: I also tested using my `is_palindrome` function and it is significantly faster on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/1k1l6).

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest a different solution? Instead of doing int<->string conversions you can test to see if a number is a palindrome this way:

```
bool is_palindrome(int number, int base = 10)
{
    int rebmun = 0;
    for (int temp = number; temp != 0; temp /= base) {
        rebmun = (rebmun * base) + (temp % base);
    }
    return number == rebmun;
}
```

Then your test becomes:

```
if (is_palindrome(c) && (c > h))
```

Comment: Looks good, would you be able to explain it in more detail though? I don't really understand what it does, just that it works.

Comment: @Leinad177: The key idea is using `temp % 10` to isolate the least siginificant digit of `temp`. Every step of the loop it multiplies `rebmun` by 10 to shift the value "left" and then adds the last digit from `temp`. Until `temp` becomes zero the digits are moved from `temp` to `rebmun` one at a time. Note the parameter `base` defaults to 10 for decimal numbers but you can pass 2 to test for binary (base 2) palindromes. This will come in hand for another Project Euler problem :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, correct indentation might make it clear:

```
int h = 0;
for(int a = 100; a<1000; a++)
    for(int b = 100; b<1000; b++)
        int c = a * b;

if ((c == reverse(c)) && (c > h))
    h = c;
```

With some extra brackets:

```
int h = 0;
for(int a = 100; a<1000; a++)
{
    for(int b = 100; b<1000; b++)
    {
        int c = a * b;
        if ((c == reverse(c)) && (c > h))
            h = c;
    }
}
```

As for the `itoa` issue, its signature is:

```
char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
```

so you can't just write `itoa(x)` and expect it to return a string.

There are however better way to convert an `int` to a `string` in C++

- if you have C++11, there `std::to_string`
- otherwise, a `std::stringstream` will do the job.

Like so:

```
#include <sstream>

int reverse (int x)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << x;
    string s(ss.str());
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return (x);
}
```

Note that this won't return the `int` reversed though.

Comment: Ah okay, how would i go about making it return the int reversed?

Comment: @Leinad177 different question.

Comment: You're missing an std:: before string and before reverse and there are missing parentheses to the ss.str() function call.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur there's a `using namespace std;` at the begining of the file, so the qualification is not necessary.

Comment: Did not see that (though you are using std:: before stringstream :D ).

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur force of habit (whereas the rest of the code is copy-pasted from the question) ;)

Comment: `using namespace std;` Many don't like this! @SO:)