# C++ stringstream how to reset it on 2nd loop

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear stringstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848087/how-to-clear-stringstream)

I have this c++ command

```
//siteurl and filename are of string type


stringstream ss;
ss << "lynx -dump '" << siteurl << "' > " << filename;
```

On first loop, everything ok. But on second loop i realize it just append instead of create a new record

as i troubleshoot using cout it give me this, I realize the command is append instead of overwrite on 2nd loop, how do I null or reset or overwrite first record of ss (stringstream) on 2nd loop/usage.

```
Webparser: lynx -dump 'http://sg.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=USDSGD=X' > file.txtlynx -dump 'http://sg.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=EURUSD=X' > file.txt
```

What i want is on 2nd loop it will be this output

```
Webparser: lynx -dump 'http://sg.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=EURUSD=X' > file.txt
```

I am new to C++, thanks for all help, greatly apperciated.

Comment: [This might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848087/how-to-clear-stringstream)

Comment: Please add the loop code

Comment: I am actually calling the function webparser twice, and its just append on 2nd use.

Comment: Issue solved with answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `ss.str("")` to make it empty.

But it is better to define `ss` inside the loop, so that each time it's a new variable:

```
for(/*.....*/)
{
   stringstream ss;
   ss << /*....*/ ;
}
```

That is,  make it a scope variable, e.g function-scope or block-scope, so that when it goes out of scope it is destructed, and when it comes back, it gets created again.

Making it a scope variable is less error prone than using `ss.str("")` to make it empty. I mean, what if you forgot to do `ss.str("")`?  In many cases, when you need to write `ss.str("")` indicates that you *actually* need to make it a scope variable, so that you could define it again, either in a loop (as shown above), or entirely a new variable, probably with a different name.