# stringstream odd behavior after string with one word

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have this code for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    stringstream ss;
    string buffer,first_word;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        getline(cin,buffer);    // getting line
        ss.str(buffer);         // initializing the stream
        ss>>first_word;
        cout<<first_word<<endl;
        ss.str(string());       // cleaning stream
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with this input:

```
line one with spaces
line two with spaces
alone
line four with spaces
```

The output I expect is just the first words of the lines, like this:

```
line
line
alone
line
```

But I am getting this:

```
line
line
alone
alone
```

So, `stringstream` is not updating after getting a line that only has one word.

Please explain this to me, I don't want the right answer with code, I want to know why.

Thank you.

Comment: The SS has already encountered eof so you need to reset the flag before reusing it. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848087/how-to-clear-stringstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bothered to check the state of the stream, you will see this line:

```
    ss>>first_word;
    if (!ss.good()) std::cout << "problem." << std::endl;
    cout<<first_word<<endl;
```

Does indeed output "problem."

```
    ss.str("");
    ss.clear();
```

Fixes the problem.