# Parsing command line in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line-arguments, stringstream

Not really asking about parsing command line arguement but rather the code (C++) to read them in

I have wrote in MSVC2010. Select Project\DEbugging\Command Line Arguement), I have written the following

```
"testvid" 10000 15000
```

all separated by space

FOr my read in code, I have used string stream to read them in

```
string folder;
int begin;
int end;

if(argc = 4){
    std::stringstream ssArgConverter;

    folder = argv[1];

    ssArgConverter << argv[2];
    if(ssArgConverter >> begin)
    {
       // success
       ssArgConverter.str("");
    }

    ssArgConverter << argv[3];
    if(ssArgConverter >> end)
    {
       // success
       ssArgConverter.str("");
    }

}
```

HAve tested the program but I seem to have problem reading in the last argument. THe printed value for the argument in my program is

```
folder : testvid
begin  : 10000
end    : -89456273
```

Just cant figure out what is wrong. Need some help here. Thanks

Comment: Note:  If the `ssArgConverter` fails for reading `argv[2]`, you still need to get it out of the error state (probably by `clear`ing the error state).

Comment: BTW, what were the issues when you singly stepped through each statement with the debugger?

Comment: Why are you assigning the value 4 to `argc` in your `if` statement?

Comment: I have 3 arguments and one function name... so I reckon the argc value to be 4

Comment: under debugger... the arguments value seem to be correctly displayed but it somehow cant be read into the int iend

Comment: @user1538798:  OK, but `if(argc = 4){` is assigning 4 to `argc`, whereas `if(argc == 4){` compares them.

Comment: @indiv ooops...sorry...typo...you are right, it should be == 4... have mistyped it down here

Comment: the same problem still occurs even with argc == 4

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your stringstream, not set its content to "".

```
string folder;
int begin;
int end;

if(argc == 4){
    std::stringstream ssArgConverter;

    folder = argv[1];

    ssArgConverter << argv[2];
    if(ssArgConverter >> begin)
    {
       // success
       ssArgConverter.str("");
       ssArgConverter.clear();
    }

    ssArgConverter << argv[3];
    if(ssArgConverter >> end)
    {
       // success
       ssArgConverter.str("");
       ssArgConverter.clear();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** this question is pretty similar to: [How to clear stringstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848087/how-to-clear-stringstream) and the accepted answer has a pretty good explanation.

So you actually should use .str("") or .str(std::string()) and .clear()

Comment: Thanks for the help! Didnt know that would need to have an additional .clear(). Have been just using the .str("") method whenever I am parsing data in a file and it has always work for me