# how to clear the content in the String stream.?

Tags: c++, string, stream, inputstream, stringstream

can any one tell me how to clear the content of the stringstream..?
i tried the following but it didnt work.

```
stringstream ss;
ss<<"bala"<<"murugan";
cout<<ss.str();         //Output balamurugan
ss.str().clear();
ss<<" hi";
cout<<ss.str();
// output is balamurugan hi
```

my required output is " hi" alone..
Pls tell me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're doing is clearing the string that is **returned** from the stringstream, not the **internal** string. You'll have to actually do the `ss.str("")`

See here:
[How do you clear a stringstream variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable)

Answer (score 4):

The "clear()" member function is inherited from ios and is used to clear the error state of the stream.

For clearing the contents of a stringstream, using:

```
stringstreamObject.str("");
```

Comment: In the case used by the OP, the `clear()` is used on the string, not the stream...

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
ss.str("");
```

This makes the stream empty!