# Change variable text

Tags: c++, sdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++, how do you clear a stringstream variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable)

I have a problem with a string i want to use to display in my loop.

I set it up like this in my loop:

```
//while {
 std::stringstream s;
 s << "Hello";

  font_surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,s.str().c_str(),font_color);
  apply_surface(x,y,font_surface,screen);   

  s << "GoodBye";
  if(font_surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,s.str().c_str(),font_color);
  apply_surface(bx,by,font_surface,screen);


//end loop }
```

The problem i have is the output first shows `Hello` then in the other location it has `HelloGoodBye`, i need to clear the content before i add `Goodbye` so i only see that in the second location on screen.

So how would i clear the information of `Hello` before I change it to `Goodbye` ?

Comment: It seems like using a `std::string` would be a better option. `std::string s = "Hello"; /*call functions*/ s = "Goodbye"; /*call functions*/`

Comment: I was suggested the current method i use because i will add variables to my strings for output which will be holding ints.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can use `s.str("");`, then. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable

Comment: Works a charm thanks! If you want answer the Q and I will tick it for rep :)

Comment: It's probably better as a dupe, seeing as how the question does boil down to exactly the other's title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use a stringstream, call

```
s.str("");
```

to clear it