# Converting a string to an int

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm getting random numbers after running the line `convert >> quarter`, I figure I have to clear stringstream out before I run it to convert again, but how would I go about doing that? And could someone explain what's going on during: (I found this as a solution but don't quite understand it)

```
    stringstream convert(tokens[1]);
    convert >> quarter;
```

-

```
Play parse(string toParse){
    vector<string> tokens;
    string play = toParse;
    string oName, dName;
    int x, quarter, minutes, down, yardstogo, startloc, playdesc;
    for(int y=0; y<10; y++){
        x = toParse.find(",");
        tokens.push_back(toParse.substr(0,x));
        toParse = toParse.substr(x+1);
    }
    stringstream convert(tokens[1]);
    convert >> quarter;
    convert.str(tokens[2]);
    convert >> minutes;
    convert.str(tokens[6]);
    convert >> down;
    convert.str(tokens[7]);
    convert >> yardstogo;
    convert.str(tokens[8]);
    convert >> startloc;
    playdesc = findPlay(tokens[9]);
    Play a(quarter, minutes, tokens[4], tokens[5], down, yardstogo, startloc, playdesc, play);
    return a;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: How to clear a stringstream (extremely searchable): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable

Comment: You don't need to clear it because you're reinitializing it with `convert.str(...)`.

Comment: I was hoping for an explanation on top of that, Chris. Barmar, do you know what I would get bad values then? Quarter and minutes are both ints, when I convert the string of quarter to an int, it's successful, when I convert minutes, I get a very large number.

Comment: What are you calling the function with?

Comment: PlayList.push_back(parse(line));

Answer (score 1):

If you keep doing it this way, you need to call clear() after calling str():

```
stringstream convert(tokens[1]);
convert >> quarter;                // Conversion 1
convert.str(tokens[2]);
convert.clear();
convert >> minutes;                // Conversion 2
...
```

The problem is that the first conversion reads the entire string, which means that it sets the iostate of the stream to eof.  Calling str() does not reset the iostate. You have to do it manually.

In your code the iostate is eof on all the later conversions, so no conversion is even attempted.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the atoi() function wich is faster than the stringstream conversion method.

Like so:
quarter = atoi(tokens[1].c_str());
minutes = atoi(tokens[2].c_str());
...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `<string>` function stoi (C++11)...

```
quarter = stoi(tokens[1])
```