# std::stringstream only supports one input at a time?

Tags: c++, std

Since `std::stringstream` is a stzream, and according to the [documention](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) here, you can perform any operation a stream supports.

So I expected the following sample to work, but it seems it doesn't. I'm using MingW with gcc 4.8.3.

**Variant A:**

```
std::string s;
std::stringstream doc;
doc << "Test " << "String ";
doc << "AnotherString";
doc >> s;
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

**Variant B:**

```
std::string s;
std::stringstream doc;
doc << "Test ";
doc << "AnotherString";
doc >> s;
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

The output of this is only

```
Test
```

While I expected that it would concatenate the individual strings until I read from the stream back what I put there.

So what is the approperiate way to concatenate strings? Do I really have to read out each one individually and concatenate them manually, which seems quite awkward to me in C++.

Comment: `stream >> s` only reads one word from the stream. It doesn't matter what kind of stream it is. Use `getline` if you want the whole line instead of one word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is putting each of the strings into `doc`, so that its content is:

```
Test String AnotherString
```

Then when you extract using `doc >> s`, it only reads up to the first whitespace. If you want to get the entire stream as a string, you can call `str`:

```
std::cout << doc.str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: @Devolus If you know it's all going to be one line in the stream, you can do `std::getline(doc, s);`. If not, you could do `std::istreambuf_iterator<char> eos; std::string s(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(doc), eos);` to get the entire content of the stream.

Comment: Yeah, it's only one line per loop. I found an answer hwo to clear the stream here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable so for completeness it would be good to add this link to the answer, as the behaviour is q bit different as might be expected if the stream is not cleard when reading the content. I suppose getline does this?

Comment: @Devolus `getline` will extract. Sure, you could do `str()` and then clear, that's one solution.

Answer (score 1):

It will only read one word till a white-space by using `stream >> s`. Besides @JosephMansfield's answer of using `str()`, alternatively you can use `getline()` (works perfectly if you the string doesn't contains new lines):

```
getline(doc, s);
```