# C++ compiler does not recognize std::stringstream::swap

Tags: c++, c++11, g++4.8

I am trying to compile the following code with g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7):

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    auto x = 1;
    stringstream s1, s2;
    s1.swap(s2);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
g++ -g -std=c++0x -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:8:5: error: ‘std::stringstream’ has no member named ‘swap’
  s1.swap(s2);
     ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

According to [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/swap/) it should work. Using different -std flags (gnu++11, c++0x etc.) didn't help. What am I missing?

Comment: The thing missing might be that it simple isn't in the GCC C++ standard library for GCC 4.8.2. You might want to try GCC 4.9.

Comment: Take a look at row [27.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011). Doesn't seem to be fixed in [GCC 4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011)

Comment: As compliant as GCC can be, little missing things like this can be just plain irritating.

Comment: It's not available yet in GCC but it is in clang.

Comment: Sounds like a job for clang!  Like GCC only faster and with clearer error messages!

Comment: @0x499602D2 In which version of Clang? Because in v3.4 it doesn't or messing something up http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6569afb96f558703

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It doesn't for GCC4.9 either this feature is not implemented yet.

Comment: @40two Clang 3.4 but I ran it from the cppreference page. For some reason it works there.

Comment: It works from cppreference because clang's standard library, [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/), is used. They implemented C++11 back in 2011 (because, unlike GCC's library, there was nothing to be backwards-compatible with)

Comment: For reference, it appears to be available in GCC 5.1 (see row 27.8 [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the GCC implementation status:

> **Section**: 27.5
>   **Description**: Iostreams base classes
>   **Support**: Partial
>   **Comments**:
>
> - **Missing `move` and `swap` operations on `basic_ios`.**
> - Missing `io_errc` and `iostream_category`.
> - `ios_base::failure` is not derived from `system_error`.
> - Missing `ios_base::hexfloat`.

more info [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x)