# Redirect from a std::ostringstream to another std::ostringstream

Tags: c++, std, c++03, ostringstream

I need write data from some `std::ostringstream` to another `std::ostringstream`. Of course, I can use `str()` function

```
std::ostringstream in;
std::ostringstream out;

in << "just a test"; // it's just an example. I mean that stream in is filled somewhere
...
out << in.str();
```

I'd like to know if there is more *direct* way to do the same.

Comment: how are you able to read on ostringstream? Shouldn't this "std::ostringstream in;" be "std::istringstream in;" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reassign the associated buffers:

```
os2.rdbuf(os1.rdbuf());
```

That effectively aliases the ostream.

In fact, you can even construct `ostream` directly from a streambuffer pointer IIRC

---

Similarly, you can append the whole buffer to another stream without reassigning:

```
std::cout << mystringstream.rdbuf(); // prints the stringstream to console
```

Answer (score 1):

The copy assignment operator/copy constructor are deleted. However, you can use the member function `swap` (C++11), or `std::swap`, to swap the content. Or, you can use the move assignment operator (C++11) to move one into the other. This solution works only in the case when you don't care about the content of the source stringstream.

Example:

```
out = std::move(in); // C++11
out.swap(in); // C++11
std::swap(out, in);
```

PS: I just realized that g++ does not compile any of the above lines (it seems it doesn't support move/swap for ostringstream), however, clang++ compiles it. According to the standard (27.8.4), swap/move should work.
See [C++ compiler does not recognize std::stringstream::swap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24429441/3093378)