# Conversion from int to string

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I want to enter numbered objects into an array. Each object's element has to be numbered depending on its position on the array. I can't figure out why the string index keeps the previous values when it is converted as the loop goes on.
For example. First place is 0 and as the loop goes on its becomes 01,012,0123 and so on.
 here's that part of the code I have problem with

```
 stringstream convert; 
    int N;
    int k;
srand ((long) 123456);
N=rand()%100+1;
NewTable=new Employee[N];


for(k=0;k<N;k++){
    string name,surname,number="";
    convert<<k;
    number=convert.str();
    cout<<number;
    name="John_"+number;
    surname="John_"+number;
    NewTable[k].SetEmployee(name,surname,13*k,3*k);*/
```

}

I also thought that by reinitializing the string of the number at the the start of the loop it will solve the problem, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not [clearing the stringstream buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable) and thus appending stuff to it at every iteration

```
for (k = 0; k<N; k++){
    string name, surname, number = "";
    convert.str(""); // You should reset its contents
    convert << k;
    number = convert.str();
```

Edit: or, as James noted, it might be better to re-create the stringstream each time if there's more involved (furthermore you only posted a snippet of code):

```
for (k = 0; k<N; k++){
    string name, surname, number = "";
    std::ostringstream convert;
    convert << k;
    number = convert.str();
```

Comment: This isn't 100% sure; there's more state than that in a stream.  The best solution is to just create a new `std::ostringstream` each time in the loop.

Comment: I decided to create a new std::ostringstream in each loop. Thank you both for your answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want a virgin `std::ostringstream` each time in the loop, then just create a new one each time in the loop.  Although theoretically, you can reset everything to get the stream back into a virgin state, it's far from trivial, and not necessarily 100% sure.  The simplest is just:

```
for ( int k = 0; k < N; ++k ) {
    std::ostringstream convert;
    convert << k;
    std::string number = convert.str();
    //  ...
}
```

(As a general rule, it's best not to define a variable until you
need it, and to initialize it immediately in the definition.)