# stringstream adding an extra zero

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am facing a problem with the below code.

```
short int decrypted0[] = {0,2};
string message = "22";
string string0 ="";

for(i=0;i<message.size();i++)
{        
     ss<<decrypted0[i];
     string0+=ss.str();     
}
```

Why does after the second iteration `string0` have a value `"002"` rather than `"02"`?

I tried with VS and Qt, Same results.

Comment: Does `string0` start out as `"0"`?

Comment: Either that or `ss`.

Comment: Well, how about putting `string0+=ss.str();` after loop?

Comment: `std::stringstream` is created outside the loop, so it doesn't empty between loop iterations.

Comment: But that's not my logic. What I shown was a sample case, loop may go for 100. Same problem.

Comment: even if I try ss.clear()?

Comment: Show me how exactly.

Comment: Problem solved , I tried  ss.str(std::string());

Comment: Wrong fix: Follow @LogicStuff advice and put the stringsteam in the lloop

Comment: @DieterLücking : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/in-c-how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable   see the top rated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::stringstream::str()` does not empty the stream, it's more of a snapshot of the current internals.  The clear its internal buffer use `ss.str("")`.

This means that your loop gives after the first iteration:

```
    ss.str() == "0"
    string0 == "0"
```

and then the after the second iteration you get:

```
    ss.str() == "02"
    string0 == "002"
```

Much easier would be to do:

```
    for(i=0;i<message.size();i++)
         ss<<decrypted0[i];
    string0 = ss.str();
```