# error: no matching function for call to 'std::strstream::str(std::string)'

Tags: string, c++11, stream

im trying to clear std::strstream using stream.str("") ( [How do you clear a stringstream variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable) ) but im getting :

`error: no matching function for call to 'std::strstream::str(std::string)'`
`note: candidate is:`
`note: char* std::strstream::str()`

im includeing : `#include <strstream>`

Comment: It's `stringstream`. You're missing letters.

Comment: right , write it as answer to be more helpful & ill accept it , but why it is compiling fine when i romove that function call , and i can you strstream class to serve all other purposes

Comment: I can't really write a meaningful answer since I haven't written C++ in like 2 years. This just stood out while I was scrolling.

Comment: i don't know how did i wrote that meaningless comment full of mistakes ,  this is the correct version : ".. but why it is compiling fine when i remove that function call , and i can still use strstream class to serve all other purposes ?"

Comment: There exists [`std::strstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstream) class. But it doesn't have a method named `str` taking `std::string`.

Comment: yes i know but why there is two versions with one missing that exact function , there must be some other details