# Extra character from StringStream to String in C++

Tags: c++, stringstream

I was writing a code in C++ 11 that would read some lines and print the first word of each line. I decided to use getline and stringstream.

```
string line, word;

stringstream ss;

while(somecondition){
    getline(cin, line);
    ss << line;
    ss >> word;

    cout << word << endl;
}
```

I tried testing this piece of code with the following input:

```
a x
b y
c z
```

The expected output would be:

```
a
b
c
```

But the actual output is:

```
a
xb
yc
```

Could someone please explain why this is happening?

Things I have tried:

1. `ss.clear();` inside the while loop
2. initializing the strings to empty inside the while loop: `word = "";`

Nothing seems to work, and all produce the same output.

3. However, when I declared the `stringstream ss;` inside the while loop, it worked perfectly.

I would be very glad if someone could explain why putting the stringstream declaration outside the while loop may cause the occurance of extra character.

Also I used `g++` compiler with `--std=c++11`.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20792/5923139) of any help?

Comment: `ss << line;` ***adds*** to the string stream.

Comment: And the [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) function doesn't do what you might think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ss.clear()` does not clear the existing content of the stream, like you are expecting. It resets the stream's error state instead. You need to use the `str()` method to replace the existing content:

```
while (getline(cin, line)) {
    ss.str(line);
    ss.clear();
    ss >> word;
    cout << word << endl;
}
```

Otherwise, simply create a new stream on each iteration:

```
while (getline(cin, line)) {
    istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> word;
    cout << word << endl;
}
```