# How to properly empty stringstream buffer?

Tags: c++, stream, buffer, stringstream

I have read [How do you clear a stringstream variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731/how-do-you-clear-a-stringstream-variable) to clear the buffer by `stringstream.str("")`, or in other words - setting empty string. But if I do so, it won't clear it:

*date.hpp*:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>

#define fmt "%m/%d/%y"

class Date
{
    std::stringstream buffer;
    struct tm date;

    template <class T>
    void insertbuf(const T &);
    void inserttime();
    std::string getFromIn(std::istream &);

public:
    //ctors
    Date();
    Date(const char *str);
    Date(const std::string &s);
    Date(std::istream &in);
    Date(const Date &d);

    //operators
    Date &operator=(const Date &rhs);

    //general
    const std::string getAll() const;
    int getMonth() const;
    int getDay() const;
    int getYear() const;
};
```

*date.cpp*:

```
template <class T>
void Date::insertbuf(const T &val)
{
    if (!buffer.rdbuf()->in_avail())
    {
        buffer << val;
    }
}

void Date::inserttime()
{
    buffer >> std::get_time(&date, fmt);
}

Date &Date::operator=(const Date &rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        buffer.str("");
        insertbuf<std::string>(rhs.buffer.str());
        inserttime();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Now in function `insertbuf`, I will `<<` to the buffer only if there is no other data. So in the `operator=`, which its left-hand-side (the object itself, or `*this`), has some data in the buffer and thus I have to clear them. I am trying to do so by setting the buffer to empty string `buffer.str("")` or equivalently `buffer.str(std::string())`, but it seems, that will not set it. From here:

*main.cpp*:

```
int main()
{
    Date bar = "11/23/2020";
    Date foo = "11/21/2020";
    cout << "before operator= " << foo.getAll() << endl;
    foo = bar;
    cout << "after operator= " << foo.getAll() << endl;
}
```

output:

```
before operator= date: 11/21/2020
after operator= date: 11/21/2020
```

As I can see the buffer was not cleared in the `operator=` function, because the buffer did not changed (The output should be `11/23/2020`, the `insertbuf` function probably did not get over the `if statement` because the buffer was not empty, even though I set it to empty string), why? And how to properly clear the buffer of `std::stringstream` then?

An exmaple:
https://godbolt.org/z/h6zofr

The reason, behind the question is here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252456/how-to-implement-simple-date-class-in-c

Comment: The condition is to avoid `foo = foo`, or self-assignment. I am not doing self-assignment, so it should be ok

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Based on what you posted I cannot reproduce the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/v84oKa (forget my last comment, it was non-sense ;)

Comment: Ok I did not want to mess here with full implementation, but I will try to do so to godbolt an paste link to post

Comment: please include a [mcve] in the question. If you don't want to post too much code, you can reduce it, but please make sure that what you post is complete, such that others can reproduce your problem

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64943474/edit) your [mre] into your question rather than posting as a link in the comments

Comment: the code in the link is also incomplete btw. I had to add more to make it compile: https://godbolt.org/z/h6zofr. Consider that any piece of code that others have to add, means that others are not looking at the same code you do.

Comment: @idclev463035818 jj, sory, I editted the post

Comment: this is the code that is currently in your question: https://godbolt.org/z/nsK59x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that calling `buffer.str("")` doesn't reset the stream state flags so if a previous operation failed or reached the end of the stream no other reads will succeed. The following should fix the issue:

```
buffer.str("");
buffer.clear();
```

Your code seems unnecessarily convoluted. If all you are trying to do is convert dates to and from strings I recommend using Howard Hinnant's [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library which is now also part of [c++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: It was just for learning purposes of implementing classes, I would use std-lib class for date in real project of course

Comment: Anyway, I am not yet very familiar with streambuf to know, which its flags are important (otherwise I would not care about clear(), which clears the flags). You said, the previous operation failed. I see no place in the code, where I am creating object from `const char*`, where would the buffer of `stringstream` should fail. So why do I have to clear the flags, when in nowhere the buffer should not fail. Can you please explain?

Comment: And also, in what place (line) from the main function does the buffer "reach the end of stream"? Where? (just to want to understand it)

Comment: `inserttime` sets the `eof` and `fail` bits as your format string is incorrect (should be `%m/%d/%Y`), even with the corrected format string it still sets the `eof` flag as it reads to the end of the stream

Comment: The reason behind the question, is here

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252456/how-to-implement-simple-date-class-in-c